# Using generics keys for methods returning hashmaps

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have a function that takes a map where keys can be of multiple types and values are always Integers. I need to perform operations on the values ignoring the keys and return the map at the end.

```
public Map<Sometype, Integer> doSomething(Map<Sometype, Integer> map, Integer total) {
    Map<Sometype, Integer> result = new HashMap<Sometype, Integer>();

    for (Sometype key :  map.keySet()) {
        result.put(key, map.get(key) * 2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The map keys can be Integers, Booleans and Enums. Is there any way to apply generics so that I can use this method with any map type?

Comment: Sure, just parameterise on `SomeType` (or use `T` by convention).  i.e.: `public <T> Map<T,Integer> doSomething(Map<T,Integer> map, Integer total) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can make your method generic on `Sometype`.

```
public <Sometype> Map<Sometype, Integer> doSomething(
        Map<Sometype, Integer> map, Integer total) {
    Map<Sometype, Integer> result = new HashMap<Sometype, Integer>();
    for (Sometype key : map.keySet()) {
        result.put(key, map.get(key) * 2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

That could also be written like

```
public <T> Map<T, Integer> doSomething(Map<T, Integer> map, Integer total) {
    Map<T, Integer> result = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    for (T key : map.keySet()) {
        result.put(key, map.get(key) * 2);
    }
    return result;
}
```